# Spivaks chapter 7 theorem 9

Tags: calculus, limits, polynomials, proof-explanation

I am a student trying to get a better understanding of calculus and I've been working my way through Spivak's Calculus book. I am stuck on his proof on *chapter 7, theorem 9, pg. 123*, that all polynomials of odd degree have a root. What I cannot grasp is that he assumes that $|x|>1$, $2n|a_{n-1}|,...,2n|a_0|$. What I don't understand is why the input value *x* has to be greater than all of these terms. I know that he later shows the inequality to be less than $\frac{1}{2}$, but why?

Comment: You have been around for a month. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) around here?

Comment: Isn't that what I used?

Comment: At some spots. But, for instance, you wrote |x|>1 instead of $|x|>1$.

Comment: Oh sorry ill edit that.but do you have any advice on the problem itself?

Comment: I'll post an answer.

Comment: Although arguably off-topic, it is worth mentioning two alternate (simple) proofs, assuming that each coefficient of the polynomial of odd degree is a real number.  One approach is that since the coefficients are all real numbers, the complex roots must occur in conjugate pairs of the form: (r + is), (r - is).  The other approach is that WLOG $a_n > 0,$ which implies that  $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = -\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = +\infty.$  Therefore, the intermediate value theorem kicks in.

Answer (score 1):

At that point, Spivek has already stated that$$\left|\frac{a_{n-1}}x+\frac{a_{n-1}}{x^2}+\cdots+\frac{a_0}{x^n}\right|\leqslant\frac{|a_{n-1}|}{|x|}+\frac{|a_{n-1}|}{|x^2|}+\cdots+\frac{|a_0|}{|x^n|}.$$The RHS of this is$$\frac{|a_{n-1}|}{|x|}+\frac{|a_{n-1}|}{|x|^2}+\cdots+\frac{|a_0|}{|x|^n}.$$So, if $|x|\geqslant1$,$$\left|\frac{a_{n-1}}x+\frac{a_{n-1}}{x^2}+\cdots+\frac{a_0}{x^n}\right|\leqslant\frac{|a_{n-1}|}{|x|}+\frac{|a_{n-1}|}{|x|}+\cdots+\frac{|a_0|}{|x|}.$$And now, if $|x|\geqslant2n|a_k|$, for each $k\in\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$, it follows from the previous inequality that$$\left|\frac{a_{n-1}}x+\frac{a_{n-1}}{x^2}+\cdots+\frac{a_0}{x^n}\right|\leqslant\frac12.$$That's his goal.

Comment: Oh ok and the subscript in the polynomial terms $a_{n-1}$ ..$a_k$ are just arbitrary terms in the polynomial like that of a sequence correct?

Comment: No, they are not arbitrary. They are the coefficients of the polynomial.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but does he make $|x|\geqslant 1$ in order to stop the terms being divided by x getting bigger

Comment: No. It's because then, for each $k\in\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$, $|x|^{n-k}\geqslant|x|$, and therefore $\frac{|a_k|}{|x|^{n-k}}\leqslant\frac{|a_k|}{|x|}$.

Comment: I think you have made an error k cannot =0

Comment: @Thehomeschooler Why is that?

Comment: Because then $|x|^k$>$|x|$ would not be strictly true

Comment: And exactly *where* did I claim that $|x|^k\geqslant|x|$ when $k=0$?

Comment: Ohh sorry I apologise but in the last part of your answer you stated that the summation of the terms is $\le$ $\frac{1}{2n}$ which cannot be true since it should be strictly less than

Comment: The goal of this is to help you understand Spivak's proof, and what Spivak writes, near the top of page 124, is$$\left|\frac{a_{n-1}}x+\frac{a_{n-2}}{x^2}+\cdots+\frac{a_0}{x^n}\right|\leqslant\underbrace{\frac1{2n}+\cdots+\frac1{2n}}_{n\text{ terms}}=\frac12.$$So, why “it should be strictly less than” exactly?

Comment: Well we already stated that by the triangle inequality the 2 summations were $\le $ but if we took x satisfying the conditions we wanted for x then the equal to part dissapears as the left hand side is therefore never going to be equal to $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: It is easy to see that, if $|x|>1$, then the inequality will be strict indeed.